# Multiplexer circuit

Tags: multiplexer, humidity

I would like to design a circuit to measure the humidity of the soil by connecting 
sensors to a 16:1 MUX . I have never worked with MUX and i dont know which one to use or where to begin. Can you help me please. Thank you.

Comment: As your avatar suggests, Google is probably a reasonable place to start. Read about multiplexers on Wikipedia, then search "analog multiplexer" and read through some datasheets. Then come back here if you have a _specific_ question.

Comment: Which sensors are you using and what are they being read by i.e. what's going into and out of this mux.

Answer (score 0):

You will probably need something like:

[image: schematic]

<sup>[simulate this circuit](/plugins/schematics?image=http%3a%2f%2fi.stack.imgur.com%2fLIqSM.png) – Schematic created using [CircuitLab](https://www.circuitlab.com/)</sup>

where the AnalogMux will have 16 inputs: Y0 .... Y15, instead of "0" and "1" as shown here for this digital-mux symbol.